# Decorator in python

Tags: python-3.x

### Decorator in Python

I am trying to write this code and I want to it run with self of class. Below is my code:

```
import typing as tp 
def wrapper_f(f: tp.Callable) -> tp.Callable:
    def wrapper(self, f: tp.Callable, *args, **kwargs):
        return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

class a:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.__n__ = n
        self.__dict_path__ = {}
    @wrapper_f
    def add(self, name):
        def decorator(f):
            self.add_new(name, f)
            return f
        return decorator

    def add_new(self, name, f):
        self.__dict_path__[name] = f
   
    def get(self, name):
        return self.__dict_path__[name]()

k = a('Hallo')

@k.add('hello')
def help():
    return "Hello =)))"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(k.get('hello'))
```

And when i run it. And Taddaaa! It not working =((((

```
>>    @k.add('hello')
>>  File "D:\Python\Learn\Advanced\decorator2.py", line 4, in wrapper
>>    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
>>TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Help me please! I don't understand why it not run and how to fix it.
Thank you guys.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.